# What is the better way to add new row in a table in mvc4?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, datatable

How  can I add new row after clicking Addrow button. Is this possible to add new row with jquery?

```
<td>
      <input type="button" id="btnnew" value="AddRow" />
      </td>
```

Comment: Where's your jQuery code?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Where do you want to add it to? What should it contain? Does it need data that's loaded from your server?

Comment: Strange this question got one upvote.....why upvoted this question????

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery?rq=1

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/Bz23B/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new row and append it to the parent table

```
$("#btnnew").click(function (){
        $(this).parents("table").append("<tr><td>test</td></tr>");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to call this jquery on the client click event of the button and add new row in table using jQuery:

```
$("#btnnew").click(function (){
    $('#myTable > tbody:last').append('<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>');
}
```

Comment: You can't really tell if this would work from the example given

Answer (score 0):

Create a new TR and add it to table based on table id

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnnew").bind("click",function(){
var tr=$("<tr>");
$("table tbody").append(tr);
});

});
```